# Accessing a value of a string defined in a interface of constants

Tags: java, string, reflection, constants

I have a constant interface file like so ->

```
public interface MyConstants {
    String CONSTANT_ONE = "foo";
    String CONSTANT_TWO = "hello";
}
```

How do I iterate over this to get the values of the constant? I saw a method using `reflect` where you can access it like this ->

```
Field[] interfaceFields = MyConstants.class.getFields();
for(Field f : interfaceFields) {
   f.get(f.getName());
}
```

This returns an object but I want it to be of type String. I know I can typecast it but what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: "*I know I can typecast it but what's the correct way of doing this?*" typecast.

Comment: Yup, typecasting is the only way.  Such is the nature of reflection:  it’s generalized by nature.  If you want strong typing, avoid using reflection.  Note that defining an enum would give you both type safety and the ability to list all constants in a typesafe manner.

Comment: Well, to be precise in case of String you can also call `toString()` method like `String str = f.get(null).toString();`, but in case of other types casting is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to make this safe, i.e. allow you to cast the Object values to Strings without getting a ClassCastException.

1. Use `instanceOf` to check the actual Class of the Object reference.
2. Check the type of the field before accessing it.

```
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SO62746826 {
    public interface MyConstants {
        String CONSTANT_ONE = "foo";
        String CONSTANT_TWO = "hello";
        int CONSTANT_THREE = 1; // now we have this field casting each of the values will throw a ClassCastException on this one
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] interfaceFields = MyConstants.class.getFields();
        for(Field f : interfaceFields) {
            Object o = f.get(null);
            if (o instanceof String) {
                String s = (String)o;
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            // or
            if (f.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                String s = (String)f.get(null);
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```